# Adding forms to admin panel django

Tags: python, django, forms, admin

i have this task in tasks.py :

```
@app.task
def startcraw(base,url,emails):
    mylist= crawler(base,url,emails)
    answer= ', '.join(mylist)
    form=CrawlUpForm()
    form.data['site']=base
    form.data['max_links']=url
    form.data['max_emails']=emails
    form.data['emails']=answer
    save_it= form.save(commit=True)
    save_it.save()
    return answer
```

i am trying to make new form that contains the details above and the answer received from fun crawler so it will be seen in admin panel...
is there a simple way to add it?

Comment: What is CrawlUpForm() 's model?

Comment: a poor try to make a form

Comment: maybe but you call .save() method. Saving by which class? May you share the code of the model ?